# Broken folder behavior in OS X 10.6.7 Finder

Tags: mac-osx, samba, operating-system

We're running into a problem with certain files and folders on our Windows 2003 R2 file share. The problem only affects OS X 10.6 clients.

Certain files and folders on the share seem to lose their filetype association. For 10.6 clients, the file or folder becomes greyed out. Older OS X clients (ours here are running 10.4, I don't have a 10.5 machine to test with) and windows machines have no problem.

In addition to becoming greyed out, if it's a folder, the icon displayed in the list view is the generic document icon. (You know, the blank piece of paper with the top-right corner folded down) Quick look and Get info both still indicate the "kind" is folder, but double-clicking the folder does nothing. The folder behaves completely normally in the terminal, only finder has the issue. Renaming, moving, or copying the folder to a local drive does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Is there any pattern to which files & folders this happens with?  Also, try running `ls -leO@d` on something that's having the trouble, and see if it reports any interesting file attributes (actually, try that on a local copy as well, and see if that shows anything different).

Comment: ls -le0@d just turned up some ACLs on the file. I cleared those just as a test. No luck. There's no pattern that we've detected yet. It seems to happen at random. So far, we've seen it affect .doc files, folders,.xls and .pdfs. Files created by at least 3 different users (all using OSX 10.6) have experienced the issue.  At least one of the files affected (a folder) was created by a Windows client, but OS X 10.6 clients can't open the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this out. Someone on the team noticed that all the affected folders of files had create dates that were in the 1940s.

It turns out that OS X 10.6.7 doesn't deal very well with files or folders that have invalid create dates. The fix is to use SetFile to set the create date to something sane.

ex:

```
[bfinch@mymac]$ GetFileInfo BustedFolder
directory: "/Volumes/MyVol/BustedFolder"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 02/14/1946 03:34:56
modified: 05/05/2011 15:02:38
[bfinch@mymac]$ SetFile -d 02/14/2006 BustedFolder
[bfinch@mymac]$ GetFileInfo BustedFolder
directory: "/Volumes/Int-IT-Sup/BustedFolder"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 02/14/2006 02:14:00
modified: 05/05/2011 15:02:38
```